# EF Core - Trouble by adding an entity to db-context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a problem adding an entity to the DB context:
The Product objects come from a json object and contains a Manufactor object (1:n relationship)

```
var products = ctx.Products.ToList();

foreach (JToken j in jObjects)
{
    Product product = j.ToObject<Product>();
    products.Add(product);
}
count++;

ctx.Products.AddRange(products);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

The following error appears when saving:

> The instance of entity type 'Manufactor' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ManufactorId'} is already being tracked.
> When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

How can I exclude the existing manufacturers?

Regards

Comment: You might want to exclude the `Manufactor` from the `Product` JSON using [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties).

Comment: But how to set the relation in this case?

Comment: If you do store the `ManufactorId` and save it to the db, The connection should be made. If the Id's are not fixed, you have a problem. Maybe you should then `JsonIgnore` the ID's and do a lookup of the existing elements, maybe on Name base or something.

Comment: the manufactors are already in the database and their Id´s are fixed - so this is not the problem. But Adding a product (including manufactor) the db context tries to insert also the manufactor.
What i want to do is to insert the product just with the manufactor foreign key..

Comment: If you put a `JsonIgnore` on the `Manufactor` and **_not_** on the `ManufactorId`, then the link should be made automatically. I'm assuming `Manufactor` is a virtual property?

Comment: Yes, but the property ManufactorId is part of the Manufactor-Object.. so if i ignore this, i can´t set the property hmm?

Comment: Ah, yes. I understand that your class `Product` doesn't have a property `ManufactorId`. If you have a virtual property to a class, e.g. `Manufactor`, EF will automatically map the `ManufactorId`: just look in the table in the database. This property will however not be visible in C#, unless you explicitly add it to your class. [Read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key). However, the next problem is that your JSON will likely not have the correct ID property field. You need to deserialize manually

Comment: @MarekSämann Please [edit] your question to include the source code of the `Manufactor` and `Product` class. Also add the JSON string which was used to build the `jObjects` variable. You also don't need to load all the `Project` entities from the database to just add a new entry.